# design window showing grey interface with written... iBinder.death recipient android

Tags: android, android-studio, android-layout

my design window in android studio is not working ...it is showing iBinder.death recipent

[image: image here]

Comment: Please also show the XML layout so we can try to reproduce the issue

Comment: the image is in the link below the question ..